# Prevent multiple JQuery scripts from breaking the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Both of these scripts need to use the jQuery library, but they are overriding each other. How do I make 2 or more jQuery/Javascript code that use the same library run at the same time? I'm trying to get script.js and the youtube js to both work.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.youtubepopup.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({
            autoplay: 1,
            draggable: true,
            hideTitleBar: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried inserting noConflict, but this breaks both.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({
            autoplay: 1,
            draggable: true,
            hideTitleBar: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm a designer figuring out javascript through trial and error, so hopefully someone can explain what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the script.js file

```
$(function () {
    function filterPath(string) {
        return string.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
    var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');
    // Any links with hash tags in them (can't do ^= because of fully qualified URL potential)
    $('a[href*=#]').each(function () {
        // Ensure it's a same-page link
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if (locationPath == thisPath && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname) && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
            // Ensure target exists
            var $target = $(this.hash),
                target = this.hash;
            if (target) {
                // Find location of target
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $(this).click(function (event) {
                    // Prevent jump-down
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Animate to target
                    $(scrollElem).animate({
                        scrollTop: targetOffset
                    }, 400, function () {
                        // Set hash in URL after animation successful
                        location.hash = target;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
    // Use the first element that is "scrollable"  (cross-browser fix?)
    function scrollableElement(els) {
        for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i < argLength; i++) {
            var el = arguments[i],
                $scrollElement = $(el);
            if ($scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0) {
                return el;
            } else {
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0;
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                if (isScrollable) {
                    return el;
                }
            }
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

Comment: To clarify, what errors are you seeing in your Chrome Developer tools or Firebug. If you don't have them. Google them and download them, you'll love them!

Comment: doesn't say anything, the scripts just don't work. If I comment out script.js, then the other script works, and vice versa. But they won't work at the same time.

Comment: oh I see. I don't know how to correctly debug Javascript with Firebug, but the Firebug "Console" tab is empty, "Script" tab says "Access to restricted URI denied," and the "DOM" tab says $ undefined...

Comment: @grace can you post those errors? i mean the full "report".

Comment: If the two plugins break each other, we will need their code. noconflict won't help you in here.

Comment: @grace: When the plugins throw an error that $ is not defined, throw out your noConflict-code. Yet, "access to restricted URI denied" can also be the origin - then we'll need that URI.

Comment: @joseph are you looking for the report from the DOM tab?

Comment: @Bergi the "access to restricted URL" is for the scripts that link to googleapis. I can paste the attached js files I'm using

Comment: @grace there should be a console tab on Firebug. what does it say, can you include it as well?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, noConflict doesn't help unless you got another library in the page that you are not telling us (like dojo or mootools). There must be something wrong with the order. always have this order in your scripts and css:

- external styles
- in-page styles
- script libraries
- script plugins
- external user scripts
- in-page user scripts

and so (urls shortened for clarity):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.youtubepopup.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({
            autoplay: 1,
            draggable: true,
            hideTitleBar: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or, there must be something that prevents execution in `script.js`. Try validating the script with [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's any difference between this and my answer. Why this s +1'ed but not mine...

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, it really cleaned up my code. So with this, the script.js works but the youtube no longer works. How do I export the error report from Firebug so you can see?

Comment: And to clarify, both scripts work fine independently of each other. Just not together

Comment: @Joseph here's the error report from JSLint '$' was used before it was defined.
$(function() {
line 1 character 11Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.
$(function() {
line 3 character 5Missing 'use strict' statement.
 function filterPath(string) {
line 5 character 9Expected '.' at column 13, not column 9.
  .replace(/^\//,'')
line 5 character 24Missing space between ',' and ''.
  .replace(/^\//,'')
line 6 character 9Expected '.' at column 13, not column 9.
  .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this might help, if you are sure that another library will also use jQuery's `$` sign:

```
<!--jQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--jQuery UI-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--A jQuery plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.youtubepopup.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();    //Relinquish $
</script>
<!--Another library-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

<!--Do stuff here-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({
            autoplay: 1,
            draggable: true,
            hideTitleBar: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there rule here to switch all "$" in every scripts to "jQuery" if you have $.noConflict();? So if you do jQuery.noConflict();, then $ would remain as is?

Comment: Just tried this - the video player now works, but the script.js doesn't

Comment: @grace - Try removing `$.noConflict()`.

Comment: Removing noConflict just breaks both the scripts, so nothing works :\

Comment: @grace - I have taken a look in `script.js`, and it doesn't seem like anything is overriding jQuery. In fact, it is *using* it. Maybe there's something wrong in your script. Did you check the console?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Following Joseph's instructions closer, I moved the script.js below the in-page user script so the 2 scripts required for youtube to work are grouped together.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.youtubepopup.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({
        autoplay: 1,
        draggable: true,
        hideTitleBar: true
    });
});
<script src="script.js"></script>
</script>
```

Thanks everyone!